# node.js variable scope with routes separation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, variables, scope

my routes are defined in an external folder

> ./routes

here's the way i define the routes in my server.js file

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.post('/validation', register.valid);
```

the register.valid module, which is originally written in

> ./routes/validation.js

is responsible for creating a new user account and register it into a database (MongoDB).

How can i access an object from server.js in validation.js ? First, i thought declaring the object before defining my routes would resolve the case, but actually it doesn't seem to be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your current code already does work (that is, you receive the posted data), but you need access to another object from validation.js.

If your code works, then you probably have this line in server.js:

```
var register = require('./routes/validation');
```

And you need acess to the variable `obj` in the validation module. You could have a function inside the validation module:

```
var foo;
exports.configure = function(obj) {
    foo = obj;
}
```

The exports mean the variable `configure` will be accessible to modules which "require" the validation module. This way you can do, inside the `server.js` module:

```
register.configure(obj);
app.post('/validation', register.valid);
```

The exact configuration of this will depend on what you are actually trying to accomplish. Sometimes, for example, it's good to have a database object stored in a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in this kind of structure `server.js` will create the `app` object and then pass that to individual routes modules via a function. I do it by having each router module export a single function like this:

```
//routes/validation.js
function setup(app) {
  app.get(....blah
  app.post(....blah
}

module.exports = setup;
```

Then I tie that together in `server.js` like this:

```
//server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
require('./routes/validation')(app);
```

See also my [express_code_structure](https://github.com/focusaurus/express_code_structure) sample project for other code organization tips.